# deliver a malicious payload via a cloned website

Tags: phishing, metasploit, kali-linux, social-engineering

I've been tasked with conducting an internal pentest, I'm relatively new to this so please bare with me.

Some time ago, I used *setoolkit* and I would have the option to clone a website and attach a malicious *jar* file, additionally the option to encode the payload was there using *Shikata ga nai*.  In the newer version of *setoolkit* I don't see this option to encode any longer. I'm able to go through the same process however this time my AV is detecting the *jar* files.

I have 2 questions , can any one recommend a paper/howto on how to recreate/clone a site and basically perform the functionality described above without using *setoolki*t? (I can use *msploit*, to create payload however I'm still learning ins and outs of this tool)

What happen to the encoding option in *SEtoolkit*? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Welcome. Paper recommendations are [off-topic](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions.

Comment: You could try the older version of SEtoolkit. As for why they removed functionality, you will have to ask the developers.